# Synchronous AMQP publish

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I know there is a number of libraries, implementing AMQP support in python. What I need, though, is a library, that will allow me to do AMQP publish in a synchronous style, because it will be used from a WSGI app, so the usual asynchronous callback-driven style of interaction with the queue broker will be a bit out of place there.

Other parts of the system use [pika](http://pika.github.com/) for AMQP support, but it is asynchronous and I'd rather not use it even though there is a sort of "blocking" connection there.

Of course, if all else fails, it is possible to maintain a Pika event loop per WSGI process. Another problem is that I've found a couple of nasty (IMO) bugs in the current stable version of Pika and I'd rather use something else.

To reiterate:

- I need to do basic.publish (with "confirm" support! so that I know when the message is not actually published)
- In a synchronous fashion
- To rabbitmq (obviously, "pure" AMQP could also work)
- From a python WSGI application

Comment: How much control do you have over the WSGI portion of the application. Are you using a framework on top of WSGI or are you calling the start_response function yourself?

Comment: @jfocht The application uses Request/Response classes, that are provided by Werkzeug. Incidentally, yes, I *am* calling start_response myself.

Comment: WSGI environment is not the reason to make asynchronous things in synchronous way

Comment: I'm in a similar boat BTW - looking for a way to do a synchronous RPC call. The only solution I've found is to use Pika's polling mechanism, basically checking for messages while connection.is_open. Still looking.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you can use the RabbitMQ's RPC for synchronous call. As you already have pika in place, there should be no much effort for you to adopt it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you check out [Kombu](https://github.com/ask/kombu) which is the underlying library used by [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/).  Both Kombu and Celery are commonly and easily integrated with Django and Flask (which is based on Werkzeug) so you shouldn't have any problems integrating it with your WSGI application.

Answer (score 0):

did you test the example code at pika documentation site?

There is a section called:
Synchronous programming style, no concurrency
http://pika.github.com/communicating.html#synchronous-programming-style-no-concurrency

It looks like what you want is a kind of RPC style call. You can find a good synchronous example at:
http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html

Comment: Both of those examples provide synchronous publishes, but callbacks on the reply. It would be best to have a method that doesn't require a callback mechanism but instead blocks waiting for a response.

Comment: Did you check puka ?
I found a discussion here:
[https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-discuss/GKgUG4_pIfI]